# API with Curl and file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm using Haveibeenpwned API, but i have troubles with continuous 403 errors. I try with Curl and file_get_contents, but i have same results...

```
 function Conn_mail($email){

        $headers = [            
            'User-Agent: Meu user agent'
        ];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{$email}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true); //Retorna o Header na saída
        //if($headers){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        //}     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
        /*var_dump($response);
        if (!$response){
            echo curl_error($ch);
        }*/ 

 }

 $json_hibp = Conn_mail('whatever@email.com');
echo $json_hibp;
```

And

```
 function Conn_mail($email){

    $context_options = array(
        'http' => array('user_agent' => 'custom user agent string')
        );

    $context = stream_context_create($context_options);         
    $con = file_get_contents("https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{$email}",false,$context);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($http_response_header);
    echo "</pre>";
    $retorno = $http_response_header[0];
    if($retorno == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
        $ret = '200';
    }
    elseif($retorno == ' HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'){
        $ret = '404';
    }
    else{
        $ret = $retorno;
    }
    return $ret;
 }

 $json_hibp = Conn_mail('whatever@email.com');
echo $json_hibp;
```

Both codes contains"User Agent" header, but Haveibeenpwned API returns 403 error (that is returned only if User Agent is missing...)

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you also need to add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 0` as curl_setopt option you can test it.. But the best way when dealing with ssl is downloading the SSL client certificate file from that url using your browser and use it to connect in curl

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is there for your protection, don't disable it. You are setting the `user_agent` header in one of your code blocks. Why not just leave the UA at the default? Just fetching the URL with `file_get_contents()` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 0` (the Raymond solution's in comments) works. `file_get_contents` does not handle very well with Haveibeenpwned API, even adding the mandatory "User-Agent" header ...